# How to hide qtip tooltip after some time has passed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using qtip ( http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/ ) to make tooltips. Now I need to show tooltips when the button is pressed and hide tooltips for example when 3 seconds have passed. My current code is not working, tooltips will sometimes go away and sometimes stay...

```
var self = $("#email");
self.qtip({
    content: error,
    tip: true,
    position: { corner: { target: 'rightMiddle', tooltip: 'leftMiddle' } },
    style: 'error',
    show: { when: false, ready: true },
    hide: { when: { event: 'mousemove' }, delay: 2000, effect: function () { self.qtip("destroy"); } }
});
```

Comment: Why are you triggering the hide on mousemove? Why not mouseout?

Comment: Well, i tried to avoid situation where tooltips would float on page after user clicked some ajax links. But I t hink that delay should be enogh to to hide this tooltip and effect is required to destroy tooltip, but for some reason this thing doesn't work on of my pages, but works ok on others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@newbie, but a response, is to tidy the code and that maybe that's the problem. eg replacing the name of the variable "self" by "this".

```
$("#email").qtip( { 
   content: error, 
   tip: true,
   position: { corner: { target: 'rightMiddle', tooltip: 'leftMiddle' } }, 
   style: 'error',
   show: { when: false, ready: true }, 
   hide: { when: { event: 'mousemove' }, 
           delay: 2000, 
           effect: function() { $(this).qtip("destroy"); }
         }
});
```

Comment: isn't it a bit violent to catch the mousemove event ? also this won't work if the user doesn't move the mouse